# Selenium Webdriver: extending Navigation causes circular dependency issue

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a very simple `app.ts` file that looks like this:

```
import { Navigation, WebDriver } from "selenium-webdriver";

class MyWebDriver extends WebDriver {
    navigate(): Navigation {
        return new MyNavigation(this);
    }
}

class MyNavigation extends Navigation {
    constructor(driver: WebDriver) {
        super(driver);
    }
}
```

I have also installed the NPM package `selenium-webdriver@4.0.0-alpha5` and I'm using NodeJS version 10.15.3.

Now when I build the project and run the `app.js` file on the command line, I get the following circular dependency exception:

```
C:\temp\MyTestNodejsProject>node app.js
C:\temp\MyTestNodejsProject\app.js:9
class MyNavigation extends selenium_webdriver_1.Navigation {
                                                ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\temp\MyTestNodejsProject\app.js:9:49)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

The above circular dependency exception is complaining about line 9 of the `app.js` file below:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const selenium_webdriver_1 = require("selenium-webdriver");
class MyWebDriver extends selenium_webdriver_1.WebDriver {
    navigate() {
        return new MyNavigation(this);
    }
}
class MyNavigation extends selenium_webdriver_1.Navigation {
    constructor(driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

**Can someone please help me figure out how to fix this circular dependency? I've spent days on this and don't see where the circular dependency is happening. Please provide a working code snippet.**

============ EDIT =============

I did a sanity check to make sure that `Navigation` was properly imported (to make sure that wasn't the issue) and modified the code to be:

```
import { Navigation, WebDriver } from "selenium-webdriver";

class MyWebDriver extends WebDriver {
    navigate(): Navigation {
        return new Navigation(this);
    }
}
```

Then when I built & ran `app.js`, the circular dependency exception went away, and `app.js` ran just fine.

Comment: This means that Navigation does not exist / was not exported. Are you following an old tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please see the edit above. Navigation does exist.